# How to do that transition with an UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to transition like this on left [**THIS**](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2015/07/settings.gif) to get back in the navigation. How can I do that with an UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer ?

I try the code in this [**raywenderlich tutorial**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/170144/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started). But it's not working, I dont why I got this errors... I need to import something or what may be ?

[image]

My code :

```
    @objc func screenEdgeSwiped(_ gestureRecognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    // 1
    let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: gestureRecognizer.view!.superview!)
    var progress = (translation.x / 200)
    progress = CGFloat(fminf(fmaxf(Float(progress), 0.0), 1.0))

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {

    // 2
    case .began:
        interactionInProgress = true
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    // 3
    case .changed:
        shouldCompleteTransition = progress > 0.5
        update(progress)

    // 4
    case .cancelled:
        interactionInProgress = false
        cancel()

    // 5
    case .ended:
        interactionInProgress = false
        if shouldCompleteTransition {
            finish()
        } else {
            cancel()
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

And, and, and... I find an other way and it's working by this way BUT there is a blank screen who is appear... I've context problem in this case.

Here is my other code :

```
func swipeBack() {
    if self.canSwipeBack() {
        let edgePan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(screenEdgeSwiped))
        edgePan.edges = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(edgePan)
    }
}

@objc func screenEdgeSwiped(_ recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
     if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
        recognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: recognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: recognizer.view!.center.y)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
     }
     else if recognizer.state == .recognized {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

func canSwipeBack() -> Bool {
    return (self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count ?? 0) > 1
}
```

Comment: Did you read the part of the tutorial where your class needs to extend `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`?

Comment: Oh man !! Thanks a lot ! Now I meet an other issue about the destinationFrame... I can't put an init in it... it's not working.